# How do I link to Bootstrap 4 and its scripts?

Tags: javascript, css, angular, bootstrap-4

According to [this blog](https://medium.com/codingthesmartway-com-blog/using-bootstrap-with-angular-c83c3cee3f4a) (which is written for BS3), I should add the following lines to the *angular.cli.json* file.

```
...
"scripts": [
  "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
  "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
],
...
```

The problem is that in the distribution I'm using (BS4 Alpha 6), there's no such file. In the *dist* directory, there's a bunch of files as follows.

```
alert.js
button.js
carousel.js
collapse.js
dropdown.js
modal.js
popover.js
scrollspy.js
tab.js
tooltip.js
util.js
```

Do I have to link to them each individually? Am I missing a minified file somewhere? I'm in *dist* so I assumed that it's the production version.

Should I go about it in a totally different way, perhaps? I'm trying the Angular CLI package since I want to test without Gulp, Grunt nor Webpack. Is there an approach where I can include, reqest, demand or append those file (preferably minified) to my web site?

The styles I've included my simply importing what I needed from the dist like this.

```
@import "~bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
```

However, I'm a bit confused on how to handle JS of the BS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking in the wrong place.

The files you are seeing are in `js/dist/`. You should be looking in `dist/js/`.

[image: file system]

Comment: Oh, so stupid... Of course! Now, it's working so answer accepted. However, I wonder if there's a nicer way to link to the files by `require`or something like that. It seems to hacky to link to the file by exiting *src* directory and then hitting *node_modules*. What's your take on it?